# Pandas groupby in filtered result not working

Tags: python, pandas

My df has two columns which are `id` and `date`.

For example,

```
   id              date
0  A  2019-10-01 10:25
1  B  2019-10-17 16:16
2  A  2019-09-28 09:29
3  C  2019-08-01 08:01
4  C  2019-09-17 17:05
5  C  2019-09-20 11:20
```

I'd like to filter my df by `date`, then group by `id`, and finally save only top N result into `newdf`.

However, filtering worked well but grouping did not work with the code below:

```
new_df = df[df.date >= '2019-09-01 00:00'].groupby('id').head(3)
```

This code makes the result like this,

```
   id              date
0  A  2019-10-01 10:25
1  B  2019-10-17 16:16
2  A  2019-09-28 09:29
4  C  2019-09-17 17:05
5  C  2019-09-20 11:20
```

but ideally `newdf` should have result like:

```
   id              date
0  A  2019-10-01 10:25
1  B  2019-10-17 16:16
4  C  2019-09-17 17:05
```

There was no compile error, what should I do?

Comment: Is this just to remove duplicates? In which case you can just do `new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id')`. Unless there's some additional aggregation you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `head(1)`. On groupby, `head` applies to each group. `head(3)` means you pick top 3 rows of each group while your desired output shows you want top 1 row of each group

```
df[df.date >= '2019-09-01 00:00'].groupby('id').head(1)

Out[725]:
  id                date
0  A 2019-10-01 10:25:00
1  B 2019-10-17 16:16:00
4  C 2019-09-17 17:05:00
```

Comment: Aha, I got it. Thank you!